# IIS only serving some images over HTTPS

Tags: image, iis, iis-7

We're using Microsoft IIS7 for our website. Everything was working fine while serving the site over HTTP, however, when switching over to HTTPS some (seemingly random) images have stopped showing up on the site. The rest of the site, all other images and the site's scripts/stylesheets load fine.

It does, however, seem that the images are in fact sent from the server to the browser, because Google Chrome's Web Inspector & Firebug both report their HTTP status as OK.

Has anyone experienced a smiliar problem? Are there any settings in the Server Manager that I can change to solve this issue?

Comment: It physical images or they are embedded in CSS like data URL?If so, remove them from CSS and them into file system as files.

Comment: They're all physical images, pretty much all of them are in the .png format. But then again, some images ARE showing, and some of them are not. Which makes it all a little confusing...